# how can i set the direction of bullet towards enemy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to shoot towards enemy .
but i cant set the direction of bullet correctly .
how can i set that ?
    this is my code .

```
    GameObject gm = (GameObject)Instantiate(BulletPrefab, BulletPoint.position, BulletPoint.rotation);
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIfIo.png)

Comment: Take a look at `Quaternion.LookRotation()`

Answer (score 0):

tnx, guys.  problem solved.
I just create an empty game object and fix the pivot by adjusting the empty game object.

```
        GameObject monster = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Bullet"));
    monster.transform.position = BulletPoint.transform.position;
    monster.transform.rotation = BulletPoint.transform.rotation;
```